# How to traverse a directory tree, find the jar files and copy them to a single directory after the build phase in the gradle build script

Tags: gradle

Our project contains multiple modules, each of them is built independently and the jar file is placed in each modules build/libs directory. In order to deploy them to our remote location, it is necessary to collect (copy) all the jar files from each module's /build/libs directory into a single directory. I created a copy task hoping that the from clause would accept wildcards, but I was wrong. Now I am adding the modules manually to the from clause, but there obviously must be a better solution for that. As a total novice in gradle scripts, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different solutions to implement this in Gradle, one simple way would be to use `subprojects` closure in order to configure the `from` clause in your copy task:

```
// a task which collects all jar files produced by the subprojects
task "collectAllJars"(type: Copy) {
    // destination directory in parent root project
    into file("$buildDir/collectedJars")

    // loop over subprojects and include there produced jars
    subprojects.each { sp ->
        from ("$sp.buildDir/libs"){
            include "*.jar"
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to create the needed dependencies between this `collectAllJars` task and the other `build` tasks from subprojects.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. I would only ask you if you could refer me to some documentation or manual where it is explained. I couldn't find it in the gradle documentation.

Comment: For the `subprojects` closure, you can refer to the Project DSL reference (https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:subprojects) which is a very good entry point in documentation, as it describes the API you can use directly in your build script.  You should also check Groovy Closure documentation (http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html): Gradle Groovy DSL is using Closure concep extensively.

Comment: Thanks again, it was fast and helpful.